# [ UPDATED ]require / include a php and pass through values to another required / included php

Tags: php, include, require

I'm going to pass through some values between two required/included php file,ex:

mysql.php:

```
<?php
    $conn = mysql_pconnect("mysql.host.com","root","password") or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
?>
```

fun.php:

```
<?php
    function fun() {
    mysql_select_db($conn);
    }
?>
```

main.php:

```
<?php
    require_once('mysql.php');
    require_once('fun.php');
    fun();
    //Output: Error that can't find $conn
?>
```

Sorry that I describe too simple. I found that I can pass anything though two included files if code run directly. But if one of them write as a function(like fun.php), the fun() can't read mysql.php's value. Anyone can give me a solution? Forgive my bad English and poor knowledge of PHP > <

Update:
One of solution I found is to insert the mysql.php's code in each functions like:
fun.php:

```
<?php
    function fun() {
        $conn = mysql_pconnect("mysql.host.com","root","password") or trigger_error(mysql_error(),E_USER_ERROR);
        mysql_select_db($conn);
    }
?>
```

But the problem is it's very very annoying(because I've wrote huge of functions) and maybe not safe because it stored username and password of the mysql server.

Comment: The ultimate solution would be not to depend on variables defined by includes of other files.  Even though php allows this, they should really be treated as local.  Your dependencies should be on abstractions rather than concrete variables.

Comment: There is nothing to improve .. its not a script issue ... Just tested the exact script with latest stable version of php and it works fine ... all i advice is for him to get a latest stable version and you think that not enough .... you should have just given him an answer instead of voting me now @Linus Kleen

Comment: include()'d scripts are treated as if they were physically cut & pasted into the script that's doing the include. in other words, top-level global variables in the included file are in the SAME scope as the file doing the including. your code will work on any modern PHP version. That suggests you're running on a stone-age copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very confusing. If I understand it, then the answer depends on how you are using the included information.

If you need to use the variables in functions, you need to declare the variable as "global" at the beginning of the function (or Class if you are OOP).

For example, if your main.php file defines the following example function:

```
function exampleFunction()
{
    global $var1; //from inc1.php
    global $var2; //from inc2.php
    //now do something with the variables and probably return a result
}
```

If you are coding OOP,

```
class SomeClass
{
      global $var1; //from inc1.php
      global $var2: //from inc2.php
      private $var3; //local to this class
}
```

Comment: but I need to say is, I will run fun() many times in different page(main.php,main1.php,main2.php...) and surely I will import mysql setting from mysql.php. But require_once wont run if I write into fun.php because it will only run once after I required it in main.php.
Even require_once can run but it will crash also because the main pages maybe placed into a sub-folder.

Comment: I think I see the problem. You need to include (require) the mysql.php file in your fun.php file. Fun cannot access the variable because it has not been included. As Marc B stated, php treats included files as if they were cut-and-pasted into the calling file.

Comment: but the problem is it means require will run twice in main.php n crash!

Comment: Move your require statement out of main.php and into the top of your fun.php file. You can chain require statements. If you require into file #1 and then require file #1 into file #2, you will have the contents of the original require statement in file #2.

Comment: not all page will use fun.php, but all page may use mysql.php, n some page wont at same folder

Comment: finally, i found global $conn in function is best solution~

Answer (score 0):

try using globals $var1 can be called as
    $GLOBALS['var1'];
or
    $_GET['var1'] = 1;
    $var2 = $_GET['var1'];

Comment: nono, in fact, inc1.php is a mysql connection handle n sth other

Comment: $_GET cant pass through these